# about the api of UIImagePickerController in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I overlay the `UIImagePickerController` with my design, and i set the showsCameraControls = NO, the zoom bar will not show both in iOS 4 and iOS 5, but the function of zoom will work in iOS 5, I can use two of my fingers to zoom in/out, but I don't want this function, so how can i stop the zoom function? I can not find this API in iOS 5 developer file, so please help me.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'zoom'.
Are you looking for -[UIImagePickerController allowsEditing]? Set it to NO, and the image simply is shown. Set to YES, and you can 'zoom' into the image, and import only that area of the image.